# Finding $F'(x)$ given $F(x) = \int_0^{x^3}\sin(t) dt$

Tags: calculus

How can I find $F'(x)$ given $F(x) = \int_0^{x^3}\sin(t) dt$ ? 
I think that (by the fundamental theorem of calculus) since $f = \sin(x)$ is continuous in $[0, x^3]$, then $F$ is differentiable and $F'(x) = f(x) = \sin(x)$ but I'm not sure...

Comment: HINT: $F(x)=1- \cos x^3$. Can you derive it now?

Comment: Why $1 - \cos x^3$ ? And I also know how to derive $\sin(t)$

Comment: $-\cos t$ is an antiderivative of $\sin t$. Now, act normally, and you can compute $$F(x) = - \cos t|_0^{x^3} = - \cos x^3 - (- \cos 0)$$

Comment: So then $F'(x) = (1-\cos (x^3))' = \sin(x^3)\cdot 3x^2$ ?

Comment: Exactly. Note that such exercizes actually don't need to compute the antiderivative, since at the very next step you derive again. So, for example, the derivative of $\int_0^{x^3} f(t) dt $ is $f(x^3) \cdot 3x^2$, no matter what $f$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have that $F(x)=1-\cos x^3$ which can then be derived. If you do not however have it, think like this. Let $g(x)=\int f(x)$ for some function. Then for $F(x)=\int^{h(x)}_0 f(x)dx$ we have
$$F'(x)=(g(h(x)-g(0))'=(g(h(x)))'=g'(h(x))h'(x)=f(h(x))h'(x)$$
where I used the chain rule, fundamental theorem of calculus and such in it.

Comment: So then $F'(x) = (1-\cos (x^3))' = \sin(x^3)\cdot 3x^2$ ?

Comment: Yepp! That is exactly $f(h(x))h'(x)$, I'd say rather than just derive $F$ think about what I wrote here because sometimes finding $F$ is impossible but $F'$ can be found through the method I gave.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might not know about antiderivatives yet, so this answer will avoid using them.

By the FTC,
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t) \, dt = f(x). $$

But you don't have $x$.  You have $x^3$.  So you'll need to use the chain rule:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^{g(x)} f(t) \, dt = f(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$

Can you take it from here?